# Fraction field and Monic Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field

Here is the question. $R$ is a UFD and $F$=Frac$R$, $E=F(α)$ is an algebraic extension of $F$.

Prove of disprove that, if the minimal polynomial of $α$ over $F$ belongs to $R[x]$, then $α$ is a root of some monic polynomial in $R[x]$.

As far as I consider, I thought the statement is false. Here is my counter example.

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $α=cos(π/9)$, it corresponds to the minimal polynomial $8x^3-6x-1$. I have no way to multiple a new polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to make it becomes a monic polynomial.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: If $f(\alpha)=0$ for some polynomial $f$ over $F$, then clearly $(uf)(\alpha)=0$ for all $u\in F^*$. Thus its minimal polynomial is usually defined to be **monic**, so that it is unique.

Comment: Yes, in field we can arbitrarily multiply or divides a non-zero number to make the minimal polynomial monic. But this question is asking about minimal polynomial in ring.

Comment: Your proposed counterexample doesn't work. The minimal polynomial of $\cos(\pi/9)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $m = x^3 - \frac{3}{4} x + \frac{1}{8}$. (As mentioned above, minimal polynomials are by definition monic: the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the unique *monic* irreducible polynomial $m \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $m(\alpha) = 0$.) Since $m \notin \mathbb{Z}[x]$, the hypotheses of the statement are not satisfied.

Comment: Huge thanks, now I think I have found the right track.